# How do I make a function only callable from another function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, lexical-closures

```
//function declerations
void func_A();
void func_B();
void func_SubA();

//main
int main(){ ... }

//function definitions
void func_A(){ ... }
void func_B(){ ... }
void func_SubA(){ ... }
```

What is the best way of ensuring that **func_SubA()** can only be called inside of **func_A()**?
I would like to receive a compiler error if **func_B()** attempted to call **func_SubA()**.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the functions you want to restrict access to as private members of a class and then use friendship to grant access.

```
class Balloon 
{
private: // private is the default. we just want to be explicit
    friend void Ken();
    friend void Barbie();

    static void Pop();
};

void Ken() {
    Balloon::Pop(); // We are allowed to pop it!
}

void Barbie() {
    Balloon::Pop(); // We are allowed to pop it too!
}

void Jack() {
    Balloon::Pop(); //  Access Denied! we must be in a time out!
}
```

Comment: +1. you can ommit `Barbie` - it only makes the answer longer. and why use `struct`?

Comment: @Elazar i've been using struct all day ;)

Comment: @Elazar and I try to use three elements in an example to avoid any confusion or additional questions

Comment: and you got comments instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is placing the definition of `func_A()` and `func_SubA()` in a different translation unit (cpp file) and making `func_SubA()` invisible outside this file by either making it `static` or placing it in an anonymous namespace:

```
// FILE main.cpp
//function declarations: possibly in a header file
void func_A();
void func_B();
// don't declare func_SubA() here
int main(){ /* ... */ }
void func_B(){ /* ... */ } // could also have its onw cpp file
// EOF main.cpp

// FILE func_A.cpp
static void func_SubA(){ /* ... */ }
/* or
namespace {
    void func_SubA(){ ... }
}
*/
void func_A(){ /* calls func_SubA() */ }
// EOF func_A.cpp
```

Another way, as suggested by JesseTG and which I'm just making clear here, is using lambda expressions:

```
//function declarations
void func_A();
void func_B();
// don't declare func_SubA();

int main(){ /* ... */ }

//function definitions
void func_A(){
    // define func_SubA through a lambda
    auto func_SubA = [](){ /* the body of func_SubA */ };
    // ...
    func_SubA(); // calls func_SubA()
    // ...
}
void func_B(){ /* ... */}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this the usual object-oriented way (private methods, etc.) or you can use lambda functions, which is a new feature in C++11.  You can read up on them [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B), they're not difficult to use.  Lambda functions allow you to access variables that are local to whatever block of code holds them.

Comment: how would private methods help in that case ?

Comment: Gather all the relevant functions into one class, make them public, and throw in some private helper methods.  Because C++ doesn't force object orientation like Java or C# do, however, I don't think very many C++ programmers would appreciate you doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations can be local, too.  If you put the forward declaration for `func_SubA` *inside* `funcA()`, you should be good.

Comment: but you *can* declare it in any other function, if you want to.

Comment: This will only work if the `func_SubA()` isn't *defined* before the attempted call. I'm not sure it's always reasonable to require such thing

Comment: Both good points.  I think the other answers are better anyway.